# How to redirect users to a directory based on Country in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, location, ip-geolocation

I would like a user from different country to be redirected to a set directory in Laravel.

I have tried this URL redirecting base on information seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48467055/redirect-visitor-based-on-country), using:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^DE$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/germany [L]
```

Now it not working. Please how can I work it out?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The question is tagged with JavaScript and PHP, which is it, client or server-side? You should share a snippet of your code, showing what you've tried and what isn't working.

Comment: We are really going to need a bit more information that that to be able to give a sensible optionion

Comment: PLEASE, put extra informaiton into the question where we can actually read it

Comment: @RiggsFolly 
Am just asking how I can redirect a visitor to a directory based on his country!

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please what extra information do you need?

Comment: RiggsFolly is saying to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71940894/edit) and add that information, not post it in the comments.

Comment: How are you getting said country information? Since you tagged Laravel the easy way to do this would be a middleware on your route and then shoot them to whatever view you want them to see.

Comment: @TimLewis I just did

Comment: Thank you. Please do that first next time; code in the comments are hard to read, but if you post it into your question, you can properly format it with syntax highlighting, etc.

Comment: @TimLewis And thats what I asked the OP to do if you read my comment :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Oh yeah, I totally understood that, but apparently I had to reiterate that for them to understand it  We're on the same page lol

Comment: @Syntax Byte Solutions - Did either of the below answers help? If so, you should accept one, to help future users find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### Step #1 - Get IP Address

Step one is easy enough

```php
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

*Actually, this may not be the most accurate method. But this is covered in more detail [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)*

#### Step #2 - Get Region from IP

The only way to associate an IP with a region, is to use a third-party service. For example, [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/).

```php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
echo $details->region; // E.g. england.
```

#### Step #3 - Redirect Page

Finally, you can then redirect the user using the above result.

```php
switch ($region) {
  case 'england':
    header("Location: https://somewhere/england",TRUE,301);
    exit;
    break;
  case 'spain':
    header("Location: https://somewhere/spain",TRUE,301);
    exit;
    break;
  case 'germany':
    header("Location: https://somewhere/germany",TRUE,301);
    exit;                 
    break;
  default:
    header("Location: https://somewhere/england",TRUE,301);
    exit;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please where do I put this code inside Laravel project

Comment: I do not know what your project looks like! You're going to need to share more info.

Comment: Thank you. 
I don't really know what to share but my project is pure Laravel Framework

Comment: You need to put this code, where you want the redirects to happen... I can give you more detailed examples, if you update your question with more info. If my answer has helped you, then consider accepting it

Comment: @SyntaxByteSolutions If this is a Laravel project, you would have a Route associated with each Country, like `Route::get('/{country}', ...);` This would then make more sense as a Middleware, where it detects your IP and redirects accordingly. Please review the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware